# Does Roslyn contain compiler source code?

Tags: roslyn

It seems that Roslyn provides new APIs to expose many compiler internal data structure for code analysis, etc. And the C# and VB compiler has been rewritten for such purpose. So can I access the compiler source besides the new APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I work for Microsoft on the Roslyn team.

Source code for the compilers is not included in the Roslyn CTP. Releasing source is something that we are considering, but don't have any firm plans at the moment.

Comment: Roslyn uses a hacked up version of CCI based off of eric lippert's blog so in theory you can see part of the infrastructure here: http://cciast.codeplex.com/

Comment: It's a relatively small portion, used primarily for emit. The bulk of the compiler (e.g. parser, binder, syntax tree API, etc.) are not available.

Comment: It's in the comments at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/10/19/the-roslyn-preview-is-now-available.aspx. Note that the Eric also mentions that we only use CCI for metadata emit and IL generation.

Answer (score 8):

Roslyn has  gone fully open source since April 3, 2014. The compiler source code is now available.
http://roslyn.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The C# and VB compilers are being rewritten in C# and VB, respectively.

However, the source for the compilers has not yet been released.
Hopefully, the source will be released in the framework source drop for an upcoming version of .Net.

You can see the compilers in ILSpy.